# Unknown column 'a.Email Address' in 'field list' error MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have the error:

> Unknown column 'a.Email Address' in 'field list in PHP from a database query.

Please can you tell me why it doesn't like the fact that I have a space between Email and Address, and how I can fix it.

Here's my full query:

```
SELECT f.*, a.*, a.Email Address, a.Avatar 
FROM Following as f 
JOIN Accounts as a ON f.followingUserID = a.id 
WHERE followingUserID = '$acID'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote it:

```
a.`Email Address`
```

And avoid spaces (or dashes, or reserved words) in/as table/column names.

Comment: edit-- I now get the error: Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'

Comment: "SELECT f.*, a.*, a.`Email Address`, a.`Avatar` FROM Following as f JOIN Accounts as a on f.followingUserID = a.id WHERE `followingUserID` = '$acID'"

Comment: @RhumSHISH, don't put a space in between a. and ` email adres `, but write it exactly like Denis did.